# How do I find if a file is managed by perforce?

Tags: perforce

How do I find if a file is managed by perforce?

I tried

```
p4 status myfile
```

but I am getting

```
myfile - reconcile to add //repo/myfile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to read the message you're getting is "this file is not managed by Perforce; run reconcile to add it".  So you're running the right command; just interpret "reconcile to add" as "this file has not yet been added".

Another option is "p4 files myfile", which will return "no such file" if the file is not in Perforce, and will return information about the depot file if it is.  Almost any Perforce command that reports file information can be used to determine whether a specific file is managed by Perforce, since they will all return something along those lines if it is not.